# strSQL formatting in Access

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am having some trouble formatting an SQL string in Access, I can never seem to debug these syntax issues with SQL strings. I have this string:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM FXData WHERE ShortCode=" & Forms!FXVolatility.cboCurve.Value & " AND MaxOfMarkAsOfDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkAsOfDate "

debug.print strSQL

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, Type:=dbOpenDynaset, Options:=dbSeeChanges)
```

which prints

```
SELECT * FROM FXData WHERE ShortCode=USD.XS AND MaxOfMarkAsOfDate=#3/31/2016# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkAsOfDate
```

However this gives me a "Too Few Parameters, expected 1" error.

All the fields and their associated values that are referenced in strSQL exist in the referenced table. What could the error be?

Also if you've got any resources on how to debug/identify these specific access SQL formatting issues I'd be happy to hear them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In SQL, strings need to be put in single or double quotes. Thus, your output should look like this:

```
... WHERE ShortCode='USD.XS' ...
```

Thus, your code becomes:

```
strSQL = "SELECT * FROM FXData WHERE ShortCode='" & _
         Replace(Forms!FXVolatility.cboCurve.Value, "'", "''") & _
         "' AND MaxOfMarkAsOfDate=#" & MaxOfMarkAsofDate & _
         "# ORDER BY MaxOfMarkAsOfDate "
```

The `Replace` ensures that any single quotes occurring *within* `cboCurve.Value` are properly escaped.

---

Note that it is recommended to use *parameters* instead of string concatenation to "fill" values into an SQL statement. An example for how to do this in MS Access can be found in the answer to this question:

- [VBA OpenRecordset Producing Too few parameters. Expected 2. Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24336077/87698)

Comment: thank you that fixed the problem! I appreciate the resource as well